# Is there any way to automatically perform test cases on an android application?

Tags: android

Is there any way to automatically perform test cases on an Android application?

When you finish an android application, you need to test all of the features of the app, in other words you need validation. But since there are so many tests which need to be performed, you need something like a robot to test all of the features.

This is important especially when you have some changes in the code in the future. So all test cases should be repeated and it takes a long time to manually perform such tests.

How do you validate your app? Do you have a robot to automatically perform test cases or you do it manually?

Comment: Here is the list of some Android application testing tools:
Robotium.
MonkeyRunner Ranorex.
Appium Studio.
Appium.
UI Automator.

Comment: Thanks , Considering I have download and upload features too, which one do you suggest

Comment: you can use Appium or UI automator.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can preform automation testing of android mobile application using tool **Appium** and **Selenium**. Most imp thing is that Appium and Selenium are open source.

Using appium we can perform automation testing for this we required followings.

1. Appium Server. 
   http://appium.io/
2. Selenium Stand-alone Web Driver.
   [enter link description here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
3. Java or python or ruby and many more but given are popular.
4. Debug apk and android studio
5. Android real device
6. Java client
   [enter link description here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
7. Any IDE such as Android studio or eclipse.

After that we have to set environment in windows or mac application and we have write script to for each functionality.

It is easy to write and use. I guess it was help full and download link are given.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: if you are satisfied then please accept the answer. UI automatoris not popular as appium. :) So chose wisely before implementing.

Comment: How can I accept the answer ? Is there any button to accept ?